# How to fill multidimensional array with empty arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to initialize a two-dimensional array with empty arrays so I can add elements to them in a larger composition using `Array.push`.  However, when I add to the inner arrays, they all get added to.  Here is a simple example:

```
const arr = Array(3).fill([]);
arr[0].push(42);
```

Now `arr` is `[[42],[42],[42]]` but I was hoping for `[[42],[],[]]`.

I think the problem is `Array.fill` is putting the same referenced empty array into each slot.  How do I get fill to make a distinct empty array at each slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const arr = [...Array(3)].map(_ => []);
arr[0].push(42);
console.log(arr);
```

Or [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 3}, _ => []);
arr[0].push(42);
console.log(arr);
```